# sencha touch add row of list that has been removed to different index of list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I really need some idea on this. Basically, i'm working to sort list by click a button. If i click up button, the list will go up which the index of selected list will reduced by one. And when i click down button, the list will go down which the index of selected list will increased by one. I used the approach to remove the selected list for a temporary, then insert the list to the different index according to user. i have settled the remove part but i have no idea on insert part. Please help.

These are the code to remove selected list.

var removeSelectedItems = Ext.getCmp('SearchRefSlipMain_List').getSelection()[0];                            Ext.getCmp('SearchRefSlipMain_List').getStore().remove(removeSelectedItems);

What left is only to insert the row of list that i have been removed to another row (different index) according to user.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not change the list, but the store that fills the list.
If this does not help, can you setup a fiddle here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

(just save it and add the link to the fiddle in your question)

I changed your answer, which should have the same result, but way faster:

```
function RowDown() {
    var direction = 1,   // 1 or -1
        treatmentDetail = Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List'),
     // or use reference
     // treatmentDetail = this.lookup('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List'),
        record = treatmentDetail.getSelection()[0],   //list id
        store, index;

    if (!record) {
        return;
    }

    store = treatmentDetail.getStore(),
    index = store.indexOf(record);


    index = index + (1 * direction);

    if (index >= store.getCount() || index < 0) {
        return
    }

    store.remove(record);
    store.insert(index, record);
}
```

Comment: might be good practice to leave your solution here. If someone else found your question helpful, there should be a solution with it.

Comment: here i attach my answer above =)

Comment: Ext.getCmp('SearchRefSlipMain_List') is the most expensive call. Work with references and use a variable to set the component one time. Otherwise your app might slow down.

Answer (score 0):

the button:

```
        {
          xtype: 'button',
          iconCls: 'arrow_down',
          handler: function () {
               RowDown();

             }
         }
```

This is the function:

```
function RowDown(){

var direction = 1   // 1 or -1    
var record = Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List').getSelection()[0];   //list id


if (!record) {
    return;
}
var index = Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List').getStore().indexOf(record);


if (direction < 0) {
    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
        return;
    }
} else {
    index++;
    if (index >= Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List').getStore().getCount()) {

        return;
    }
}

Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List').getStore().remove(record);
Ext.getCmp('Settings_SetTreatmentList_TreatmentDetail_List').getStore().insert(index, record);

 }
```

***if move the selected list up, change the direction =  -1
*  https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?48472-how-to-move-the-grid-s-row-up-and-down (i got the solution from here, just change a bit according to Sencha Touch)

Comment: I updated my answer, to show you how you can speed up your result.